# Getting a ton of errors on this script?

Tags: python, proxy, urllib2

I have been at this for 45 minutes. I am in desperate need for help.

When I run this:

```
import urllib, urllib2

proxy = urllib2.ProxyHandler({
    'http': '127.0.0.1',
    'https': '127.0.0.1'
})
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
# this way both http and https requests go through the proxy
urllib2.urlopen('http://www.google.com')
urllib2.urlopen('https://www.google.com')
```

I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Craig.py", line 1, in <module>
    import urllib, urllib2
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 94, in <module>
    import httplib
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 79, in <module>
    import mimetools
  File "C:\Python27\lib\mimetools.py", line 6, in <module>
    import tempfile
  File "C:\Python27\lib\tempfile.py", line 35, in <module>
    from random import Random as _Random
  File "C:\Python27\random.py", line 3, in <module>
    print random.randint(0, 1) # prints either 0 or 1  (for me it printed 0)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'randint'
```

UPDATE:

Fixed the random.py issue and now get:

```
  File "C:\Python27\Craig.py", line 10, in <module>
    urllib2.urlopen('http://www.google.com')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 410, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 523, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 448, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 531, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 501: Not Implemented
```

Comment: It looks like you have a file `random.py` in the current directory. One suggestion - every "project" you work on, create a new folder - probably in the home directory,  to keep it modular. That way, such errors can be avoided.

Comment: Ok I changed it and got a new error. It is in the lower half of question.

Comment: Do not turn this into a [chameleon question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions).  Make some effort to solve your new problem, and then post a new question - including what you have done to try to solve it - if you are unable.

Comment: I have made an effort. A long hours worth. I just cant figure it out.

Comment: Try removing the https proxy, and try. I _could_ work

Answer (score 1):

You have a file in the current directory called `random.py`. Rename it to something else like `random_.py`.

Note, developing with your files in `C:\Python27` is probably not a good practice.

Comment: You shouldn't wholesale rewrite the question after I've answered it as other folks will not understand what my answer refers to. Add an update further down instead.

Comment: Agreed with David. Hence the +1. You should be either mark an explicit EDIT, or create a new question.

Comment: I didnt rewrite it. One more line got added.

Comment: You completely replaced the original traceback.

Comment: @DavidK.Hess Confusing indeed. I was wondering what kind of wizard you were to guess an existing `random.py` from that traceback (and be correct).